# ¿Por qué mi consulta en ajax solo actualizar el primer registro?

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo un detalle con mi consulta, estoy trabajando con una actualización múltiple de registros con ajax y php, al momento de enviarle mis inputs al ajax solo actualiza el primer registro y yo quiero que actualice los registros que capture, no se si sea mi consulta del update o el porque no esta recorriendo todo el array, o que estará pasando si alguien me pudiera orientar para saber que me hace falta, por favor

Este es mi código con el paso información a los inputs

```
<?php


        $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ordenes where orden=pruebas1010";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        while ( $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {   
            
           echo '<tr>
           <td hidden><input type="text" id="id" value="'.$row['id'].'" disabled><br> 
           <th><input type="text" id="item" value="'.$row['items'].'"><br>       
           <th><input type="text" id="precio" value="'.$row['price'].'"><br> ';
        }?> 
    
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#update").click(function(){
                    let id=$("#id").val();
                    let item=$("#item").val();
                    let precio=$("#precio").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'update.php',
                        method:'POST',
                        data:{
                            id:id,
                            item:item,
                            precio:precio
                        },
                        success:function(response){
                            alert(response);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

## update

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');


$id = $_POST["id"];
$item=$_POST["item"];
$precio=$_POST["precio"];


$sql="UPDATE ordenes set id='$id',items='$item', price='$precio'
where id=$id";
if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){
    echo "DATA updated";
}
?>
```

Comment: Fíjate bien que creas ```let id, let sku``` y ```let tienda``` pero en cambio luego pasas en el **data** de AJAX los siguientes parámetros: ```id:id, item:item, precio:precio``` cámbialo por ```id:id, item:sku, precio:tienda```

Comment: Hola @Diablo, perdón ya le cambie  los let a un solo nombre, y solo sigue actualizando el primer registro es decir el primer id no actualiza los demás

Comment: Era solo una pequeña observación, digo quizás no te estaban llegando los datos correctamente, luego me imagino que en tu ```select``` donde ```orden=pruebas1010```, quieres comparar un ```string```, entonces debe ser algo como ```orden='pruebas1010'```

Comment: He escrito una respuesta, pero justo después he visto que no te molestas en marcar como acertadas las respuestas que te dan, así que he borrrado mi respuesta. Mira [tour] para ver como funciona este sitio.

Comment: @SJuan76, antes de responder mejor fíjate primero si marco o no.

Comment: geek_root, @SJuan76 tiene razón: en todas las preguntas que has hecho no hay ninguna respuesta seleccionada. Debes seleccionar la respuesta que mejor contesta tu pregunta (siempre y cuando la respuesta te haya sido útil), ademas puedes votar otras (o la misma) resputas. Cuando lo hagas verás que la tu pregunta queda con el recuadro con fondo verde. De está manera todos sabemos que has recibido la repuesta desea y no seguimos respondiendo la pregunta.

Comment: Hola @nachospiu, de acuerdo amigo lo hare enseguida, muchas gracias

Comment: De nada @geek_root!!!

Comment: Hola @nachospiu, no más no me queda, ya hice lo que sugeriste en el update puse un bucle for, pero solo sigue actualizando el primer registro.

Comment: Hola! Actualiza la pregunta con los cambios que hiciste (los puedes agregar a continuación). Chequea que estén llegando en el POST los datos de todas las filas de la tabla (y que los mismos sean correctos), debés estar mandando solo una fila. Ahora el id de cada campo tiene que tener concatenado el número de fila, y tienes que enviar todas las filas en el POST.

Comment: Gracias @nachospiu, lo hare

Comment: De nada @geek_root!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varios errores al armar la tabla:

- No cierras los tags td, input, ni el tr.
- Has utilizado tags th para los renglones.
- No veo el tag <table> en el código, quizas no has compartido esa parte del mismo.
- Los mismos campos en diferentes renglones de la tabla tienen el mismo id (deberías agregegar un contador para concacatenar al id, que se incremente en cada iteración).
- Al hacer click en "update" estás enviando los datos de un renglón solamente, deberías enviar todos los renglones (recuerda que ahora los ids tiene un número concatenado).
- En el update deberías poner en bucle para que la query se ejecute por cada renglón.
- Te recomiendo Utilizar Prepared Statments con place holders, y no queries planas. Tiene dos ventajas:

  1. Mayor seguridad: evitas ataques de tipo SQL Injection.
  2. Mayor rapidéz:
     ya que el motor de base de datos parsea la query una sola vez, y no
     cada vez que la ejecutás.

```
<?php

$i = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>
            <td hidden><input type='text' id='id{$i}' value='{$row['id']}' disabled /></td>
            <td><input type='text' id='item{$i}' value='{$row['items']}' /></td>
            <td><input type='text' id='precio{$i}' value='{$row['price']}' /></td>
        </tr>";
    
    $i++;
}

?>
```